# SQL Server como vincular o nome de uma coluna à uma variável externa?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, servidor

Bom dia srs

Eu fiz um código em SQL que separa um item de cada registro de uma coluna sem repetir, e está funcionando corretamente, segue código abaixo:

```
SELECT Tab_Dados_Escolha.Nome_Produto FROM Tab_Dados_Escolha
GROUP BY Tab_Dados_Escolha.Nome_Produto
```

porém eu gostaria de substituir o nome da coluna onde será feito essa rotina por uma variável externa, assim eu poderia utilizar esse mesmo código para as outras colunas sem precisar reescrever outro código e não estou conseguindo até o momento, alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Cara, é isso, só colocar o nome do database(não obrigatório) e executar

```
declare @comando varchar(max),
        @tabela varchar(max),
        @coluna varchar(max),
        @database varchar(max)

set @tabela = 'Tab_Dados_Escolha'
set @coluna = 'Nome_Produto '
set @database = ''

set @comando = 'SELECT '+@tabela+'.'+@coluna+',count(*) as quantidade FROM '+@database+'.dbo.'+@tabela+' GROUP BY '+@tabela+'.'+@coluna

exec(@comando)
```